# Are $1-x^2$ and $-2x$ analytical functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, legendre-polynomials

We assume $x$ is a real variable. According to "Advanced Engineering Mathematics 10th Edition", a differential equation $y'' + p(x) y + q(x) y = r(x)$ has a power series solution in powers of $x-x_0$ if $p,q,r$ are analytical at $x = x_0$.

Now this is Legendre's differential equation:

$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + n(n+1) y = 0$ ($n$ is real)

According to the book, this differential equation has a power series solution in powers of $x$ because $\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}$ and $\frac{n(n+1)}{1-x^2}$ are analytical at $x = 0$. But is that true? It is trivial $n(n+1)$ is analytical but I think $-2x$ and $1-x^2$ are not analyticacl: I mean these two functions aren't seemed to fulfill Cauchy-Riemann equation, which you see in complex analysis. (I know Cauchy-Riemann equation is used to determine if a function is regular but a regular function is analytical, I believe.)

Comment: all polynomials are of course analytic over $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$ if you work in $\mathbb C$).

Comment: The CR equations are for complex functions of complex variables. You can't really apply them to real functions of real variables. Instead, analytical usually means that the function has a converging power series at each point, which your functions do (for instance, at $0$, the power series are $-2x$ and $1-x^2$ respectively, while at $1$ they are $-2-2(x-1)$ and $2(x-1)+(x-1)^2$).

Comment: What definition of "analytical" do you have? Why don't you think that $-2x$ and $1-x^2$ fits into that definition?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So the definitions  of "analytical" are different between in real analysis and in complex analysis? I believed a real function is just a special case of a complex function.

Comment: For complex functions, being analytic and fulfilling the CR equations can be seen to be equivalent. However, being analytic applies to functions in many other contexts too. And real functions are not special cases of complex functions. A real-valued function is a special case of a complex-valued function, and a function taking complex input can be restricted to become a function that takes only real input. But these two do not talk together to make any sort of connection between $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ functions and $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are analytical.

The general definition of an analytic function (of one variable) is that for every $a$ there's a neighborhood for which there's constants $c_j$ such that $f(x) = \sum_0^\infty c_j (x-a)^j$ there (for more variables you have to sum over all combos of exponents with coefficient going with that).

Obviously this is true for every polynomial. Becase if $P(x) = \sum p_jx^j$ is a polynomial we have that $P(x) = P(x-a+a) = \sum_0^n p_j( (x-a) + a)^j$ and by binomial expansion we see that $P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x-a$ as well.

The definition is not actually different in complex analysis, it just happens that they in the complex case are the same as holomorphic (ie differentiable) functions which make some authors use that as a definition instead.

Comment: Thank you. I asked whether $1-x^2$ is analytical because, in complex analysis, I proved a regular function divided by a regular function is also a regular function. But if we use the definition of analytic functions you taught me, is it trivial to say $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is analytical at $x = 0$? I think from $\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2x} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1+x} \right)$ we can get only native powers.

Comment: It's possible to prove that products of analytical functions are analytical and division yields analytical except where the divisior is zero. For example we have $1/(1-x^2) = \sum x^{2j}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Now all of questions I had have been answered. Thank you.